# Adobe DPS Webviewer getByProductId not working

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-dps

I'm currently working on a custom storefront with the webviewer SDK. There is one thing I can't get to work is retrieving a single folio by productId from the document map. This is what I currently do:

I created a global var of the library.

```
library = adobeDPS.libraryService.createLibrary(guid, {}, createLibraryHandler, function(error){console.error(error)});
```

When I log this var all the folios are available in the document map.

Next up, I try to get a single folio from the document map. I have created a function to retrieve the folio.

```
function getFolio(productId){  
    var folio = library.folioMap.getByProductId(productId);  
    console.log(folio);  
}
```

The logged folio returns null.

I have tried both webrendition folios and normal folios.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the webviewer SDK. I spoke with the Adobe support and they will fix it in the near future.